# stop automatic full screen when dragging windows

Tags: 18.04, 18.10

I am using Ubuntu 18.04/18.10. How do I turn the snap to full screen feature OFF? This is a most annoying feature of OS these days. I run 2 screens and it is most annoying when moving to the other screen. I have turned off this function in Windows, but cannot find any function or selector to do likewise in 18.04/18.10. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Get Dconf Editor from Ubuntu Software and then go to `/org/gnome/mutter` and make `edge-tilting false`.

Comment: It's already set to false for me, but it still jumps to fullscreen when I move the top of the window "too far up", that is, if I accidentally keep moving the mouse after the window has reached the top and snapped into place.